# Enable colors in xterm (launched from Qt Creator)

Tags: c++, qt, colors, terminal, xterm

I need to use *colors* in terminal, because I am running the *Google C++ Testing Framework (unit tests)* and the output is far more readable when using colors.

There seem to be two possible solutions:

- enable colors in xterm

According to [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim) and [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/829014?start=0&tstart=0) I have run this under root with no effect

```
if [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then
        export TERM='xterm-256color'
else
        export TERM='xterm-color'
fi
```

- somehow configure Qt Creator to another terminal that uses colors
  However, there seems to be a [bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1633) in Qt Creator that forbids me to change the `Tools->Options->Environment->Terminal` to anything other than `/usr/bin/xterm -e`.

I am running latest Qt Creator 2.6.0 on Fedora 17 on GNOME3.

Note: The colors show properly when I run tests from the GNOME3's default terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I works on Qt Creator 2.6.0 based on Qt 5.0.0 (64 bit) which was built on Nov 11 2012 on Fedora 17. I downloaded it directly from homepage. This is beta2, but the final version should come before the end of the year. The solution is therefore to upgrade.